# Friendly way to redeem Custom Code from Google Play

Tags: android, android-billing, in-app-subscription

I have create a `Custom codes` which allow user subscriptions with some free trials. From the [document](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/promo#redeem), in order to redeem the code, we need to initiate the purchase bottom sheet dialog, press arrow, redeem the code.

For me, it look not friendly to user (in iOS, Custom code can redeem by URL or by call API within the app)

[image]

Is there anyway other way to redeem Custom Code from Google Play?

Comment: Hello, did you find any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to redeem the code from Google Play Store.

Open Play Store-> Click on profile picture on top right corner->Select Payments and subscriptions->Click on Redeem code. Now, you will be able to see the 3rd screen from your question.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know this is the only way.

The answer from priya-sindkar is only applicable to "One-time codes" (i.e. codes that can be used once and by a single user to install or get your 1-time IAP for free).

For "Custom Codes" (i.e. the code that can be used by many users to get an extended free trial) it seems that the only way is the one described in the question, and a further restriction is that the workflow must be done from within the app itself, just before paying for the subscription as described on [this answer](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6321495) from Google support.